# Use gcloud SDK to authentication with AppEngine App

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

The gcloud SDK is a convenient way to authenticate to AppEngine services. I would like to use these credentials to authenticate to an AppEngine app that is configured in `app.yaml` with `login: admin`. This will let me use curl to access my admin endpoints. I can get a bearer token from the gcloud SDK with `gcloud auth print-access-token`. Unfortunately the app appears to be looking for a cookie that looks like `ACSID=...`.

**Is there a way to use the bearer token I have from the gcloud SDK to authenticate to my AppEngine app by getting an ACSID cookie or otherwise?**